# Is there a way to upload video from an iPhone to Google+?

Tags: iphone, video, google

Is there a way to upload video from an iPhone to Google+?

Comment: I can upload recent videos, but videos taken before setting up google+ won't uploade to google+ account

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same way you would upload a photo.

Within the Google+ app on your iPhone.

- Tap the camera icon within the app.
- Select your video from the Camera Roll.
- Click the blue arrow in the top-right corner.
- Select some particular Recipients and maybe add some text.
- Click Share.